# UFW Firewall rule not working

Tags: networking, windows, firewall, ufw

I have an ubuntu vm which runs the UFW and a microsoft xp professional. The ip address of the ubuntu is 192.168.254.132 and so I made the xp have a static ip address of 192.168.254.131 so they will be on the same network. I tried using telnet to connect to the Ubuntu it failed, which was suppose to happen because of the implicit deny. However when I typed sudo ufw allow from 192.168.254.131 to any port 23 to allow telnet it still did not work. I do not know what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete the deny rule as the deny rule will trump the allow rule.

Because the deny is still in place, allow will not work.